# How to enable sortable columns in SlickGrid

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I'm working on getting a working SlickGrid data table running, but the most commonly available function, the ability to move columns around, eludes me. I assume I would have to remove the option that says `enableColumnReorder: false` (and of course making sure that there is no trailing comma at the end of the options), but when I do that, the grid fails to run at all. I've compared it to SlickGrid's own demo examples to try to see if there's something I'm missing, but it all seems legit. Can anybody out there clue me in to what script and/or option I'm missing?

Here's my example: http://www.tomryandesign.com/dev/datagrid/custom2/

Comment: So, you want to reorder the columns or enable sorting on your columns?

Comment: Is there a difference? What I want to do is be able to click on the column heads and move them around, and reorder them manually once the page is loaded.

Comment: You probably did this already - try setting `enableColumnReorder: true`..

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. In the `slick.grid.js` script, the default value for the `enableColumnReorder` option is `true`, so setting it to `true` in the options of the script on the page has the same effect as removing it altogether, which is that the grid ceases to function at all.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the problem was with the version of jQuery UI I was using. SlickGrid is apparently not compatible with jQuery UI 1.9.

Comment: True, the compatibility issue is being discussed here. https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/518

Answer (score -1):

Did you try `sortable: true` in the column setup object?

& then write you custom logic on sorting things.
Ex.

```
gridObj.onSort = function(e, args) {
 gridData.sort(comparer);
 gridObj.invalidate(); 
}

function comparer(a,b) {
  //returns your custom logic to sorting the rows.
}
```